# Toolbar disappears after segue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, toolbar

When using a segue from a slide out menu to other view controllers, my toolbar and navigation bar both disappear. I fixed the navigation bar disappearing by segueing to a navigation controller, which then set the desired view controller as the root of the navigation controller. However this does not fix the toolbar issue. Should this not have fixed the toolbar disappearing as well? Either way, what is the best solution to my issue?
Thanks!

Comment: your segue type is push or modal?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem using SWRevealViewControllerLibrary. In your storyboard make sure you are using "Reveal View Controller Push Controller" segue. If you have multiple segues, when you click on them you may find some things like the toolbar disappearing from the storyboard. If so then simply make a new one in the storyboard.

As for the second part of the question, from what I can tell toolbars are not by default part of a navigation controller's 'root' view, and so may change across controllers - just like how if you created a button or label in your first view, they would also change.